# Adicionar diversos selects em um só dataset

Tags: r, dplyr

Tenho o dataset abaixo e nele faço uma consolidação das categorias Mk_Cap, Exports e Money_Supply, porém cada um desses grades tem uma Unit diferente.

```
df <- data.frame(Mes=c("Jan","Fev","Mar","Abr","Mai",
                   "Jan","Fev","Mar","Abr","Mai",
                   "Jan","Fev","Mar","Abr","Mai"),
             Ano=c(2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,
                   2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,
                   2005,2006,2007,2008,2009),
             Mk_Cap=c(11:15,116:120,1111:1115), 
             Exports=c(21:25,146:150,1351:1355),
             Money_Supply=c(31:35,546:550,2111:2115),
             Unit=c("USD","USD","USD","USD","USD","200=10",
                    "200=10","200=10","200=10","200=10",
                    "CNY","CNY","CNY","CNY","CNY"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Hoje estou consolidando da maneira abaixo:

```
library(dplyr)
Money_Supply <- df %>% dplyr::select(Ano, Mes,Money_Supply) %>% dplyr::filter(df$Unit == "USD")
Mk_Cap <- df %>% dplyr::select(Mk_Cap) %>% dplyr::filter(df$Unit == "200=10")
Exports <- df %>% dplyr::select(Exports) %>% dplyr::filter(df$Unit == "CNY")

Consolidado <- base::cbind(Money_Supply,Mk_Cap,Exports)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que não seja a maneira mais correta de se fazer isso, porém hoje é a maneira que encontrei, nesse exemplo que passei tem poucas ocorrências, mas no caso prático faço isso em mais de 30 variáveis o que é extremamente oneroso, caso tiver alguma maneira mais fácil seria o ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema não é a unidade de cada coluna, mas sim que cada unidade requer uma coluna diferente. O jeito é mapear cada unidade a coluna necessária e depois juntar tudo.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(Mes=c("Jan","Fev","Mar","Abr","Mai",
                       "Jan","Fev","Mar","Abr","Mai",
                       "Jan","Fev","Mar","Abr","Mai"),
                 Ano=c(2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,
                       2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,
                       2005,2006,2007,2008,2009),
                 Mk_Cap=c(11:15,116:120,1111:1115), 
                 Exports=c(21:25,146:150,1351:1355),
                 Money_Supply=c(31:35,546:550,2111:2115),
                 Unit=c("USD","USD","USD","USD","USD","200=10",
                        "200=10","200=10","200=10","200=10",
                        "CNY","CNY","CNY","CNY","CNY"))


mapa <- list(
  "USD" = "Money_Supply",
  "200=10" = "Mk_Cap",
  "CNY" = "Exports"
)

sub_list <- mapa %>% 
  map2(
    .,
    names(.),
    ~df %>%
      filter(Unit == bquote(.(.y))) %>%
      select(Ano, Mes, bquote(.(.x)))
  )

purrr::reduce(sub_list, dplyr::left_join)
```

Comment: Pô, uso legal do reduce. Sempre acho difícil de imaginar como usar ele kkk

Answer (score 3):

Você também pode agrupar os dados por mês e ano, pegar os valores que você quer e depois tirar as colunas repetidas. É menos geral o código mas é mais próximo de sua tentativa inicial.

```r
df <- data.frame(Mes=c("Jan","Fev","Mar","Abr","Mai",
                       "Jan","Fev","Mar","Abr","Mai",
                       "Jan","Fev","Mar","Abr","Mai"),
                 Ano=c(2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,
                       2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,
                       2005,2006,2007,2008,2009),
                 Mk_Cap=c(11:15,116:120,1111:1115), 
                 Exports=c(21:25,146:150,1351:1355),
                 Money_Supply=c(31:35,546:550,2111:2115),
                 Unit=c("USD","USD","USD","USD","USD","200=10",
                        "200=10","200=10","200=10","200=10",
                        "CNY","CNY","CNY","CNY","CNY"))



library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Mes, Ano) %>% 
  mutate(
    Money_Supply = Money_Supply[Unit == "USD"],
    Mk_Cap = Mk_Cap[Unit  == "200=10"],
    Exports = Exports[Unit == "CNY"]
  ) %>% 
  select(-Unit) %>% 
  distinct()
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#> # Groups:   Mes, Ano [5]
#>   Mes     Ano Mk_Cap Exports Money_Supply
#>   <chr> <dbl>  <int>   <int>        <int>
#> 1 Jan    2005    116    1351           31
#> 2 Fev    2006    117    1352           32
#> 3 Mar    2007    118    1353           33
#> 4 Abr    2008    119    1354           34
#> 5 Mai    2009    120    1355           35
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>